# error: AgoraclientException, AgorachannelException, AgoraRtcException(-8, null), and rtmpStreaming video is not being pushed to the server

Tags: flutter

error: AgoraclientException, AgorachannelException, AgoraRtcException(-8, null), and I/agora.io(21795): (00000287): BaseStreamProxy::onRtmpStreamingStateChanged(this:0xb400007b5acdc780, url: rtmp://live-fra.twitch.tv/app/{streamke}, state: 4, errorCode: 16) I/agora, how do i solve such problems``

```
`
  `Future<void> initAgora() async {
     await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
     engine = createAgoraRtcEngine();
     addUser(0, userId);
     _client = await AgoraRtmClient.createInstance(appId);
    await engine?.initialize(const RtcEngineContext(
    appId: appId,
   channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting,
   ));
   try {
    _channel=await _client?.createChannel(channel);
   showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('created channel succesfully')),
         content:Text('')); });
    } catch (error) {
     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('error')),
         content:Text('$error')); });
     }
    try {
    await _client?.login(token, userId);
   showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('logged in succes fully $userId')),
         content:Text('')); });`
     } catch (error) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('error')),
         content:Text('$error')); });

     }
    try {
     await _channel?.join();

     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('joined succesfully')),
         content:Text('')); });
      } catch (error) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('error')),
         content:Text('$error')); });
      }
      try{
      _channel?.onMemberJoined=(RtmChannelMember member){
     setState(() {

       addUser(remote,  member.userId);
     });
     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
       return AlertDialog(
           title: Center(child: Text('member joint')),
           content:Text('${member.userId}')); });
    
      };}catch(error){
     showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('error')),
         content:Text('$error')); });
     }
    engine?.registerEventHandler(
     RtcEngineEventHandler(
        onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
       debugPrint("local user ${connection.localUid} joined");
       setState(() {
         localUserJoined = true;
         activeuid=connection.localUid!;
         });
        },
        onUserJoined: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, int elapsed){
       addUser(remoteUid, userId);
       setState(() {
         remote=remoteUid;
         remoteuid.add(remoteUid);
       });
       },
       onUserOffline: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, UserOfflineReasonType reason) {
       uidToPeerIdMap.remove(remoteUid);
       debugPrint("remote user $remoteUid left channel");
       setState(() {
         remoteuid.remove(remoteUid);
       });
        },
        onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire: (RtcConnection connection, String token) {
          debugPrint('[onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire] connection: ${connection.toJson()}, token: $token');
        },
      ),
     );
     await engine?.enableVideo();
     await engine?.startPreview(sourceType: VideoSourceType.videoSourceCamera);
     await engine?.isCameraZoomSupported();
     await engine?.getCameraMaxZoomFactor();
     await engine?.switchCamera();
     await engine?.setClientRole(role: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster);
     await engine?.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(VideoEncoderConfiguration(
      bitrate:6000,
      minBitrate:1500,
      frameRate: 30,
       orientationMode: OrientationMode.orientationModeFixedLandscape,
      ));
     await engine?.setRemoteDefaultVideoStreamType(VideoStreamType.videoStreamHigh);
     await engine?.joinChannel(
      token: token,
      channelId: channel,
       uid: uid,
      options: ChannelMediaOptions(channelProfile:ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting),              
     );
     await startStream();
    }
     static void addUser(int uids, String peerId) {
     uidToPeerIdMap[uids] = peerId;
    }
    int activeuid=0;
      int uid1=0;
   Future<void>startStream()async{
      try {
   List<TranscodingUser>transcodingUsers = [];
   transcodingUsers.add(TranscodingUser(uid: activeuid,
       x: 0,
       y: 0,
       width: 960,
       height: 540));
      LiveTranscoding liveTranscoding = LiveTranscoding(
     lowLatency: true,
     videoFramerate: 15,
     videoBitrate: 500,
     userCount: 1,
       transcodingUsers: transcodingUsers, width: 960,
       height: 540);
     await engine?.startRtmpStreamWithTranscoding(
       url: rtmpIngestUrl, transcoding: liveTranscoding);
       showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
           title: Center(child: Text('pushing successfully')),
         content:Text('')); });

        }catch(error){
       showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
         title: Center(child: Text('error')),
         content:Text('$error')); });
   
     }
    }` `

`
```

here is a sample code:
`

tried to edit the rtmpurl , tried different streaming platforms, tried reducing the settings of the video parameters eg bitrate, width,height still video is not bieng pushed. The AgoraRtmchannel &client tried to update SDK package but is already upto date .

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).